# Unique extension of a map from $X$ to a map from the free algebra

Tags: logic, category-theory, monads

Suppose we are in a category $\mathcal{C}$ and we have monad on this category, written as $(P,\sigma, \mu)$. We can consider the category of $P$-algebras. Among its elements is are the free algebras, which are of the form $(P(X),\mu_X)$, for some object $X$. In most cases, like with groups or monoids, the construction of such a 'free' object has the following universal property: If there is another object $T$, and a map $t:X\to T$, then this extends in a unique way to a lift $\hat{t}:P(X)\to T$, making the obvious triangle commute. It seems to me that this also holds in the more abstract case, for an arbitrary category and an arbitrary monad. However, I fail to find a source which elaborates on this subject explicitly, and only found a source which just mentions it as a result. Does anyone have an argument why this should, or should not, be true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is true, and (like a lot of proofs in category theory) it's really an exercise in unwinding definitions, chasing diagrams, and doing the only obvious thing at every step. What have you tried so far? Can you find any way to define the lift $\hat{t}$?

Comment: I know of the adjunction of the functor $U^P:P-Alg\to \mathcal{C}$ and $F^P:\mathcal{C} \to P-Alg$, where the first one maps an algebra to its domain, and the second one maps an object to its free algebra. So finding a map from $P(X)\to T$ corresponds with an algebra map $(P(X),\mu_X)\to (T,h)$. So my idea was to look for an algebra $(X,h)$ and then try to extract a morphism $P(X)\to T$ hence a morphism $X\to T$. However, this did not work so far.

Comment: Ah! See, this is exactly the kind of relevant context you should *always* include in your question. I was considering giving you hints toward a direct construction - but if you already know about this adjunction, then the universal property follows much more easily.

Comment: Well, I recalled this adjunction after I posted the question, so I could not have included it in the question! But still, with this adjunction in mind, I fail to construct or derive such a map $P(X)\to T$, could you give me a hint towards finding such a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you say you are happy with the adjunction $F^P \dashv U^P$, where $U^P\colon \mathsf{P{-}Alg}\to C$ takes a $P$-algebra $(X,\alpha)$ to its underlying object $X$ and $F^P\colon C\to \mathsf{P{-}Alg}$ takes an object $X$ to the free algebra $(P(X),\mu_X)$. This adjunction means exactly the same thing as the universal property you're interested in - it's just a more concise way of writing it down.

Let $X$ be an object in $C$ and let $(Y,\alpha)$ be a $P$-algebra. Then the adjunction tells us that $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) = \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,U^P(Y,\alpha)) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathsf{P{-}Alg}}(F^P(X),(Y,\alpha))$. So for every arrow in $C$ from $X$ to the underlying object of the $P$-algebra $(Y,\alpha)$, there is a unique $P$-algebra morphism $F^P(X)\to (Y,\alpha)$ from the free $P$-algebra on $X$ to $(Y,\alpha)$.

Now you'd like to know something a bit more - not just that there is a natural bijection between $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathsf{P{-}Alg}}(F^P(X),(Y,\alpha))$, but that the arrow $U^P(f)\colon P(X)\to Y$ defining the $P$-algebra homomorphism $f\colon F^P(X)\to (Y,\alpha)$ "lifts" the corresponding arrow $g\colon X\to Y$ in $C$, in the sense that $U^P(f)\circ\sigma_X = g$. To do this, we need to dig in a bit more into how the adjunction works. And there's a standard way to understand an adjunction as a universal property. You can skip this whole section if you're already familiar with it.

> Suppose $F\dashv G$ are adjoint functors, where $F\colon C\to D$ and $G\colon D\to C$. Let $X\in C$. Then in particular, we have a natural bijection $\text{Hom}_D(F(X),F(X))\cong \text{Hom}_C(X,G(F(X)))$. So the identity map $\text{id}_{F(X)}\in \text{Hom}_D(F(X),F(X))$ corresponds to some arrow $\eta_X\in \text{Hom}_C(X,G(F(X)))$. The arrows $\eta_X$ cohere to a natural transformation $\eta\colon \text{Id}_C\to G\circ F$, which is called the unit of the adjunction. Further, naturality tells us that for any arrow $f\colon F(X)\to Y$ in $D$, we have a commutative square:
>   $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
> \text{Hom}_D(F(X),F(X)) @>{f\circ-}>> \text{Hom}_D(F(X),Y)\\
> @V{\cong}VV @V{\cong}VV \\
> \text{Hom}_C(X,G(F(X))) @>{G(f)\circ-}>> \text{Hom}_C(X,G(Y))
> \end{CD}$$
>   If we start in the upper left with $\text{id}_{F(X)}$ and go right, we get $f\circ \text{id}_{F(X)} = f$, and if we go down, we get the arrow $X\to G(Y)$ in $C$ corresponding to $f$ in the adjunction. Instead, if we go down first we get $\eta_X$, and then if we go right, we get $G(f)\circ \eta_X$. In other words, $\eta_X$ is a magical arrow with the property that if we want to compute what arrow $X\to G(Y)$ in $C$ corresponds to $f\colon F(X)\to Y$ in $D$, we just have to look at $G(f)\circ \eta_X$. A slogan is that "$\eta_X$ is the universal way to go from $X$ to something in the image of the functor $G$", in the sense that for any other way to go from $X$ to something in the image of $G$, $g\colon X\to G(Y)$, it factors through $\eta_X$ as $g = G(f)\circ \eta_X$, where $f\colon F(X)\to Y$ corresponds to $g$ through the adjunction.

Ok, back to the concrete case of $P$-algebras. If you understand the adjunction $F^P\dashv U^P$, you can compute that for any $X\in C$, $U^P(F^P(X)) = P(X)$, and the unit $\eta_X$ of the adjunction is just the unit of the monad $\sigma_X\colon X\to P(X)$. So if $g\colon X\colon U^P(Y,\alpha) = Y$ is an arrow from $X$ to the underlying object of a $P$-algebra $(Y,\alpha)$, and $f\colon F^P(X)\to (Y,\alpha)$ is the corresponding homomorphism of $P$-algebras, then $f$ and $g$ are related by $g = U^P(f)\circ \eta_X = U^P(f)\circ \sigma_X$. This is exactly the "lifting" commutative triangle we wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation! However, if one only has the map $X \to T$, and $\sigma_T:T \to P(T)$, then in order to apply your construction, one needs an algebra with $T$ as its underlying object. Does such an algebra necessarily exist?

Comment: @EBP In formulating the universal property, $T$ should be the underlying object of a $P$-algebra (which is part of the data). The universal property of free groups (for example) goes like this: Let $X$ be a set and $G$ a *group*. For any map (of sets) $X\to G$, there is a unique group homomorphism $F(X)\to G$. There is no universal property if $G$ is just a set!

Comment: And no, it is not true for a general monad $P$ on a general category $C$ that every object of $C$ is the underlying object of a $P$-algebra.